# Bootstrap3: Collapsed navbar not opening on codepen but works on codeply

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

As the title says,

Built a responsive navbar with bootstrap3 but it's not opening when I use codepen.
I have loaded in bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css and I've also added jquery to make sure but it's still not working.

It is however working on codeply.

Is this a known issue with codepen or did I forget something?

http://codepen.io/kyriediculous/pen/ORpvPo

Many thanks

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">.Portfolio./</a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navCollapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-right navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>  
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to load jQuery first. In your Codepen you load Bootstrap before jQuery.

Comment: Thanks ! Too bad you didn't post as an answer so I could mark it .

Comment: Codeply automatically includes jquery when you select Bootstrap 4